# Automate SQL Server join to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, automation

I have an automated SSRS report that runs off a SQL Server SP.  A subscription then exports this to a folder each morning.  I'm not sure if this next step is possible, but maybe someone knows:

Another Excel report from an outside source will be dropped into the same folder each morning.  Is it possible to then automatically compare the two reports and delete records from my automated report that do not match?

I know I can manually import the new Excel file into SQL Server, do a join and then delete the records.  But is it possible to do this automatically?

Comment: You could definitely do this in a .Net app, but I am presuming you are wanting to use either SSRS or T-SQL?

Comment: Yes, SSRS or T-SQL.  I've used a little C#, but not enough to build something like this.

Comment: No you cannot do this without doing some ETL. Otherwise you should do like @Leonidas199x says, use C#

Comment: @plaidDK--I'm looking into using SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for SSIS. SSIS is designed to handle ETL workflows like this. I would create a package that pulls in the outside Excel and either the output from your SSRS subscription or preferably calls the stored procedure itself. You can do all the data comparison you need and then output in whatever format you need or run T-SQL statements against your source database based on the results of your comparison as appropriate to your use case. You'd deploy your package to a SQL Server setup for SSIS and create a SQL Agent job to run it at the appropriate interval.